# How to set lower limit for the highest value being displayed on Y Axis?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a chart.js line graph whereby the Y-value is a percentage from 0-100 and the X-axis represents time in seconds for the past minute. The chart is populated using live data from a socket connection that updates every five seconds.

I'm running into a problem with the Y-Axis steps being generated dynamically by chart.js. For the most part, everything is great and the Y-Axis scales according to the range of data currently being displayed. However, when the percentage is 0% or when it falls between 0 and 1, for example .654%, the Y-Axis will show display a min value of 0 and a max value of 1%. Therefore, the chart is misleading as it appears that the percentage is a high one when in fact it is less than 1%.

[image]

So my question is: how do I set a minimum value for the max value being displayed along the Y-axis?

(now before you jump to conclusions and drop a line about the stepSize property, I have tried setting the stepSize to values like 1 and 3. The problem with that, is that when the percentage values jump to 75% or above, the large number of labels required (75/3 or 75/1) ends up making the labels illegible)

Comment: Looks like you're trying to reduce the "noise" in the graph when the values are low.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the `suggestedMax` tick option for the y-axis. Use it like this:

```
options: {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        suggestedMax: 60
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

This tick value will be used as the maximum tick of the y-axis, provided that all data values are lower than this. If a data value is higher than this tick value, then a higher tick value will be automatically calculated and used instead. From the [docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales-linear-scale):

> suggestedMax
>
> User defined maximum number for the scale,
>   overrides maximum value except for if it is lower than the maximum
>   value.

You may see it in action [here](https://jsfiddle.net/j7np72fm/) and below.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Percentage',
      data: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          suggestedMax: 60
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```